# Ubuntu Partion Size Guide

Tags: installation

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my Laptop. How much I need for root, home and swap partition? I have 3GB RAM. I will use Ubuntu for installing any kind of interesting packages and doing some programming. And, another question, can I use any partition (which is being used by Windows 7) as my home folder in Ubuntu?

Comment: do you want the windows partition to be the home partition in ubuntu? i guess not. do you want a partition to be shared with windows? see link bellow. try to be explicit. with your ram you don't seem to really need swap ( if you must, it should be at least equal). For system (`/`) partition at least 8 GB, more if you think installing many programs. more for the `/home`, if you need to store files (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please keep the amount of questions limited to one per post. It's how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don’t need to put *root* and *home* on separate partitions, and the size depends on how much data you will store on your *home* as well as total space available on your hard disk. For example I myself prefer storing data on Ubuntu because on journaling file types (ex2, ex3, ex4) my data won’t get fragmented or even virus-infected and it’ll be faster to access them.

So let us know, if possible, how much space you have and where you will store your data more: Windows or Ubuntu.

For swap, you can visit this [SwapFAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq?highlight=%28%28SwapFaq%29%29#How_much_swap_do_I_need.3F); if you have much space, 3 GiB is highly recommended.